# Pass values of a pandas column as separate arguments in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has rows x y and z and columns of different names. Essentially these are three-dimensional coordinates of each name. I have imported this csv as a dataframe which looks like:

```py
 Coordinate       C1       C2       C3       C4       C5       N6
0          x  0.16620  0.20640  0.16240  0.08140  0.04370  0.08288
1          y  0.22340  0.34680  0.44090  0.41100  0.28550  0.18996
2          z  0.38187  0.42618  0.40091  0.33013  0.28793  0.31430
```

I would like to perform transformations to the coordinates such as (x,y,z)->(y,x,z). I don't have much experience with python but I find I can do this with a simple function such as

```py
def trans(x,y,z):
     return (y,x,z)
```

I am having issues with getting the values from each column in the form of x, y, and z so that I may pass them through the function to achieve the desired transformation.
I find that I can convert each column to a tuple by using

```py
tuple([tuple(co_df[col]) for col in co_df])
```

however, this will ultimately give me a tuple of tuples. I could instead turn this into a list of tuples, but then I have the issue of passing a list of tuples into my function to transform the coordinates. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does the CSV file look like? In any case, have you seen the section of the Pandas user guide on [MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but maybe a for loop would be useful

For example, to print the output of trans for each column, you could do something like this:

```
for column in list(co_df):
    a,b,c=co_df[column]
    print(trans(a,b,c))
```

This would print:

```
('y', 'x', 'z')
(0.22340, 0.16620, 0.38187)
(0.34680, 0.20640, 0.42618)
(0.44090, 0.16240, 0.40091)
(0.41100, 0.08140, 0.33013)
(0.28550, 0.04370, 0.28793)
(0.18996, 0.08288, 0.31430)
```

What are you planning on doing with the values once they been transformed? Do you need them stored in an object?

**EDIT**
Re. your question about what `a,b,c=co_df[column]` does, think about this at a single column level e.g. `co_df["C1"]`
`print(co_df["C1"])`
returns

```
0    0.16620
1    0.22340
2    0.38187
```

Doing `a,b,c=co_df["C1"]` assigns each value of `co_df["C1"]` to a, b, and c respectively.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing. This does essentially what I need it to do. What does a,b,c=co_df[column] do? Does it assign each element in the column a variable a, b, and c?
Once the data has been transformed I simply need to put it in a new dataframe with the same index and names.
If a,b,c=co_df[column] simply assigns each element of the column to a variable how would you generalize this solution, for say, when you don't know the length of the column?
Since posting this I tried transposing and then using itertuples but could not find a way to pass through and expand (with *) each element to trans.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what the code does. So I can see how the solution might be generalized, can you modify your answers so it shows how the dataframe would look please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data = ''' Coordinate       C1       C2       C3       C4       C5       N6
0          x  0.16620  0.20640  0.16240  0.08140  0.04370  0.08288
1          y  0.22340  0.34680  0.44090  0.41100  0.28550  0.18996
2          z  0.38187  0.42618  0.40091  0.33013  0.28793  0.31430
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
print(df)

  Coordinate       C1       C2       C3       C4       C5       N6
0          x  0.16620  0.20640  0.16240  0.08140  0.04370  0.08288
1          y  0.22340  0.34680  0.44090  0.41100  0.28550  0.18996
2          z  0.38187  0.42618  0.40091  0.33013  0.28793  0.31430
```

First, you can put the columns in a different order like this:

```
print(df[['Coordinate', 'N6', 'C5', 'C4', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1']])

  Coordinate       N6       C5       C4       C3       C2       C1
0          x  0.08288  0.04370  0.08140  0.16240  0.20640  0.16620
1          y  0.18996  0.28550  0.41100  0.44090  0.34680  0.22340
2          z  0.31430  0.28793  0.33013  0.40091  0.42618  0.38187
```

Second, you can re-label the columns like this (assign to df.columns):

```
df.columns = ['Coordinate', 'N6', 'C5', 'C4', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1']
print(df)

  Coordinate       N6       C5       C4       C3       C2       C1
0          x  0.16620  0.20640  0.16240  0.08140  0.04370  0.08288
1          y  0.22340  0.34680  0.44090  0.41100  0.28550  0.18996
2          z  0.38187  0.42618  0.40091  0.33013  0.28793  0.31430
```